# Joining two tables with similar columns but different values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, key

First of all, I have seen this question before :
([Two tables with similar columns but different primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431276/two-tables-with-similar-columns-but-different-primary-keys))

But there is a slight difference from my problem.

My table looks something like this :

```
Table 1
ID     Name    Salary
123    Mike    5000
129    David   4000
133    Linda   4500

Table 2
ID      Dept
0123    IT
0129    Tech Support
0133    Analytics
```

I want to join these two tables based on ID so that I can see their ID, Name, and Dept. ID in Table 1 and Table 2 is for the same person in actuality, but there is a 0 in front of the ID in Table 2 so the program treats it as unique value giving me result something like this :

```
Table result:
ID     Name    Dept
0123   null    IT
0129   null    Tech Support
0133   null    Analytics
123    Mike    null
129    David   null
133    Linda   null
```

Is there a way that I can remove the "0" from ID in Table 2 or join them somehow? They don't have other similar columns that can be used. It was supposed to be like this :

```
Table result
ID     Name    Dept
123    Mike    IT
129    David   Tech Support
133    Linda   Analytics
```

Thank you and sorry if my question is a duplicate, I can't find one similar like mine.

Comment: It just isn't a plausible scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last 3 digits of the `ID` in `Table 2` are the `ID` value that can be found in `Table 1` then you can just take the `Table 2.ID` value modulo 1000 (to strip any leading digits) and `JOIN` on that:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.Dept
FROM `Table 1` t1
JOIN `Table 2` t2 ON t2.ID % 1000 = t1.ID
```

Output:

```
ID      Name    Dept
123     Mike    IT
129     David   Tech Support
133     Linda   Analytics
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=628baacbaa4be59d42f562f584d697c0)

Comment: Okay thanks. What if the number in front is different? Like
123 = 60123
124 = 60124
133 = 60133

The 60 is prefixed that should be excluded (it is to check they are at which region), but it actually refers to the same person. Thanks

Comment: @Lutfi are they always 3 digits and 4 digits?, or just always 1 more digit in `Table 2`? Or ???

Comment: Actually, the number in front represents a region (60 is another region, 61 is another region), so the real ID is the last 3 digits.

So, 60123 = 123, 60 is region A

Sorry if I didn't make it clear.

Comment: @Lutfi no problem. See my edit, that should do what you want